# How do I delete all lines in a concatenated text file that match the header WITHOUT deleting the header? [bash]

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My apologies if this question already exists out there. I have a concatenated text file that looks like this:

```
#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8
1   1   764484  783034  1:764484:783034:clu_2500_NA 0.66666024153854    -0.194766358934969
2   1   764484  787307  1:764484:787307:clu_2500_NA -0.602342191830433  0.24773430748199
3   1   880180  880422  1:880180:880422:clu_2501_NA -0.211378452591182  2.02508282380949
4   1   880180  880437  1:880180:880437:clu_2501_NA 0.231916912049866   -2.20305649485074
5   1   889462  891303  1:889462:891303:clu_2502_NA -2.3215482460681    0.849095194607155
6   1   889903  891303  1:889903:891303:clu_2502_NA 2.13353943689806    -0.920181808417383
7   1   899547  899729  1:899547:899729:clu_2503_NA 0.990822909478346   0.758143648905368
8   1   899560  899729  1:899560:899729:clu_2503_NA -0.938514081703866  -0.543217522714283
9   1   986217  986412  1:986217:986412:clu_2504_NA -0.851041440248378  0.682551011244202
```

The first line, `#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8`, is the header, and because I concatenated several similar files, it occurs multiple times throughout the file. I would like to delete every instance of the header occuring in the text without deleting the first header

**BONUS** I actually need help with this too and would like to avoid posting another stack overflow question. The first column of my data was generated by R and represents row numbers. I want them all gone without deleting `#Chr`. There are too many columns and it's a problem.

This problem is different than ones recommended to me because of the above additional issue and also because you don't necessarily have to use regex to solve this problem.

Comment: If you have different questions, post a new question. That's what this site is about.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm worried about being punished for asking a bad question but I searched for this and couldn't find it.

Comment: Note that both of these issues can be prevented in the concatenation process. You might want to reconsider how you concatenate the files.

Comment: It needs to be said again: If you have two questions, post two separate questions. Linking between them is fine. You are *more* likely to get "punished" for violating the "one question per question" guidance than for posting multiple questions, even if they turn out to be duplicates of existing questions. If you can show us what you already searched for and how none of the answers you found worked for you, that's an excellent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following AWK script removes all lines that are exactly the same as the first one.

```
awk '{ if($0 != header) { print; } if(header == "") { header=$0; } }' inputfile > outputfile
```

It will print the first line because the initial value of `header` is an empty string. Then it will store the first line in `header` because it is empty.

After this it will print only lines that are not equal to the first one already stored in `header`. The second `if` will always be false once the header has been saved.

Note: If the file starts with empty lines these empty lines will be removed.

To remove the first number column you can use

```
sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*[ \t]*//' inputfile > outputfile
```

You can combine both commands to a pipe

```
awk '{ if($0 != header) { print; } if(header == "") { header=$0; } }' inputfile | sed 's/^[0-9][0-9]*[ \t]*//' > outputfile
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such a thorough answer

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helpful:

1. delete all headers
2. delete first column
3. add first header

```
cat foo.txt
#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8
1   1   764484  783034  1:764484:783034:clu
#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8
2   1   764484  783034  1:764484:783034:clu
#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8
3   1   764484  783034  1:764484:783034:clu

sed '/#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8/d' foo.txt | awk '{$1 = ""; print $0 }' | sed '1i #Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8'

#Chr    start   end ID  GTEX-Q2AG   GTEX-NPJ8
 1 764484 783034 1:764484:783034:clu
 1 764484 783034 1:764484:783034:clu
 1 764484 783034 1:764484:783034:clu
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
awk 'NR == 1 {header = $0; print} $0 != header' file
```

Comment: You may want to include the first occourrence of the header with a print in `NR == 1 { header = $0; print }`

Comment: Quite right, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed '2,${/HEADER/d}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Command explained:

- Starting at line 2: `2,`
- Search for any line matching 'HEADER' `/HEADER`
- Delete it `/d`